# Integrating Creative Tim's react kit, with Creative Tim's dashboard, and then with React-Redux-Firebase backend

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to figure out how to work with Creative Tim's templates.

I have the pro kit template (that gives a home page etc) and then now trying to integrate it with the Dashboard.

The routes/index.js file I currently have has:

```
import CoreLayout from '../layouts/CoreLayout'
import Home from './Home'
import LoginRoute from './Login'
import SignupRoute from './Signup'
import ProjectsRoute from './Projects'
import AccountRoute from './Account'
import NotFoundRoute from './NotFound'
import AboutRoute from "./AboutUs"
import HiringRoute from './Hiring'
import ApplyRoute from './Apply'
import PartneringRoute from './Partnering'
import MediaRoute from './Media'
import TermsRoute from './Terms'
import PrivacyRoute from './Privacy'
import DisclaimerRoute from './Disclaimer'

import HowRoute from './How'
import StudioRoute from './Studio'
import MatchRoute from './Match'
import StructuringRoute from './Structuring'
import ResourcesRoute from './Resources'
import ToolkitRoute from './Toolkit'
import FaqRoute from './Faq'
import SolResRoute from './Solres'
import SolIndRoute from './Solind'
import SolPfroRoute from './Solpfro'
import SolGrRoute from './Solgr'
import SolInRoute from './Solin'
import SolPolRoute from './Solpol'
import SolSerRoute from './Solser'
import GlossaryRoute from './Glossary'
import DiligenceRoute from './Diligence'
import DocumentRoute from './Document'
import CasestudyRoute from './Casestudy'
import LessonRoute from './Lesson'
import SolasRoute from './Solas'


/*  Note: Instead of using JSX, we recommend using react-router
    PlainRoute objects to build route definitions.   */

export const createRoutes = store => ({
  path: '/',
  component: CoreLayout,
  indexRoute: Home,
  childRoutes: [
    AccountRoute(store),
    LoginRoute(store),
    SignupRoute(store),
    ProjectsRoute(store),
    AboutRoute(store),
    HiringRoute(store),
    ApplyRoute(store),
    PartneringRoute(store),
    MediaRoute(store),
    TermsRoute(store),
    PrivacyRoute(store),
    DisclaimerRoute(store),
    HowRoute(store),
    StudioRoute(store),
    MatchRoute(store),
    StructuringRoute(store),
    ResourcesRoute(store),
    ToolkitRoute(store),
    FaqRoute(store),
    SolResRoute(store),
    SolIndRoute(store),
    SolPfroRoute(store),
    SolGrRoute(store),
    SolInRoute(store),
    SolPolRoute(store),
    SolasRoute(store),
    SolSerRoute(store),
    GlossaryRoute(store),
    DocumentRoute(store),
    DiligenceRoute(store),
    CasestudyRoute(store),
    LessonRoute(store),
    // AsyncRoute(store) // async routes setup by passing store
    // SyncRoute, // sync routes just need route object by itself
    /* Place all Routes above here so NotFoundRoute can act as a 404 page */
    NotFoundRoute(store)
  ],

})

/*  Note: childRoutes can be chunked or otherwise loaded programmatically
    using getChildRoutes with the following signature:

    getChildRoutes (location, cb) {
      require.ensure([], (require) => {
        cb(null, [
          // Remove imports!
          require('./Counter').default(store)
        ])
      })
    }

    However, this is not necessary for code-splitting! It simply provides
    an API for async route definitions. Your code splitting should occur
    inside the route `getComponent` function, since it is only invoked
    when the route exists and matches.
*/

export default createRoutes
```

The documentation for the Dashboard in the Creative Tim template format has:

src/routes/index.jsx

```
import Pages from "layouts/Pages.jsx";
import RTL from "layouts/RTL.jsx";
import Dashboard from "layouts/Dashboard.jsx";

var indexRoutes = [
  { path: "/rtl", name: "RTL", component: RTL },
  { path: "/pages", name: "Pages", component: Pages },
  { path: "/", name: "Home", component: Dashboard }
];

export default indexRoutes;
```

It then has additional files for each of dashboard, pages and RTL.

For example, the routes/dashboard.jsx has:

```
import Dashboard from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";
import Buttons from "views/Components/Buttons.jsx";
import GridSystem from "views/Components/GridSystem.jsx";
import Panels from "views/Components/Panels.jsx";
import SweetAlert from "views/Components/SweetAlert.jsx";
import Notifications from "views/Components/Notifications.jsx";
import Icons from "views/Components/Icons.jsx";
import Typography from "views/Components/Typography.jsx";
import RegularForms from "views/Forms/RegularForms.jsx";
import ExtendedForms from "views/Forms/ExtendedForms.jsx";
import ValidationForms from "views/Forms/ValidationForms.jsx";
import Wizard from "views/Forms/Wizard.jsx";
import RegularTables from "views/Tables/RegularTables.jsx";
import ExtendedTables from "views/Tables/ExtendedTables.jsx";
import ReactTables from "views/Tables/ReactTables.jsx";
import GoogleMaps from "views/Maps/GoogleMaps.jsx";
import FullScreenMap from "views/Maps/FullScreenMap.jsx";
import VectorMap from "views/Maps/VectorMap.jsx";
import Charts from "views/Charts/Charts.jsx";
import Calendar from "views/Calendar/Calendar.jsx";
import Widgets from "views/Widgets/Widgets.jsx";
import UserProfile from "views/Pages/UserProfile.jsx";
import TimelinePage from "views/Pages/Timeline.jsx";
import RTLSupport from "views/Pages/RTLSupport.jsx";

import pagesRoutes from "./pages.jsx";

// @material-ui/icons
import DashboardIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
import Image from "@material-ui/icons/Image";
import Apps from "@material-ui/icons/Apps";
// import ContentPaste from "@material-ui/icons/ContentPaste";
import GridOn from "@material-ui/icons/GridOn";
import Place from "@material-ui/icons/Place";
import WidgetsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Widgets";
import Timeline from "@material-ui/icons/Timeline";
import DateRange from "@material-ui/icons/DateRange";

var pages = [
  {
    path: "/timeline-page",
    name: "Timeline Page",
    mini: "TP",
    component: TimelinePage
  },
  {
    path: "/user-page",
    name: "User Profile",
    mini: "UP",
    component: UserProfile
  },
  {
    path: "/rtl/rtl-support-page",
    name: "RTL Support",
    mini: "RS",
    component: RTLSupport
  }
].concat(pagesRoutes);

var dashRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    name: "Dashboard",
    icon: DashboardIcon,
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    path: "-page",
    name: "Pages",
    state: "openPages",
    icon: Image,
    views: pages
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    path: "/components",
    name: "Components",
    state: "openComponents",
    icon: Apps,
    views: [
      {
        path: "/components/buttons",
        name: "Buttons",
        mini: "B",
        component: Buttons
      },
      {
        path: "/components/grid-system",
        name: "Grid System",
        mini: "GS",
        component: GridSystem
      },
      {
        path: "/components/panels",
        name: "Panels",
        mini: "P",
        component: Panels
      },
      {
        path: "/components/sweet-alert",
        name: "Sweet Alert",
        mini: "SA",
        component: SweetAlert
      },
      {
        path: "/components/notifications",
        name: "Notifications",
        mini: "N",
        component: Notifications
      },
      { path: "/components/icons", name: "Icons", mini: "I", component: Icons },
      {
        path: "/components/typography",
        name: "Typography",
        mini: "T",
        component: Typography
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    path: "/forms",
    name: "Forms",
    state: "openForms",
    icon: "content_paste",
    views: [
      {
        path: "/forms/regular-forms",
        name: "Regular Forms",
        mini: "RF",
        component: RegularForms
      },
      {
        path: "/forms/extended-forms",
        name: "Extended Forms",
        mini: "EF",
        component: ExtendedForms
      },
      {
        path: "/forms/validation-forms",
        name: "Validation Forms",
        mini: "VF",
        component: ValidationForms
      },
      { path: "/forms/wizard", name: "Wizard", mini: "W", component: Wizard }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    path: "/tables",
    name: "Tables",
    state: "openTables",
    icon: GridOn,
    views: [
      {
        path: "/tables/regular-tables",
        name: "Regular Tables",
        mini: "RT",
        component: RegularTables
      },
      {
        path: "/tables/extended-tables",
        name: "Extended Tables",
        mini: "ET",
        component: ExtendedTables
      },
      {
        path: "/tables/react-tables",
        name: "React Tables",
        mini: "RT",
        component: ReactTables
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    collapse: true,
    path: "/maps",
    name: "Maps",
    state: "openMaps",
    icon: Place,
    views: [
      {
        path: "/maps/google-maps",
        name: "Google Maps",
        mini: "GM",
        component: GoogleMaps
      },
      {
        path: "/maps/full-screen-maps",
        name: "Full Screen Map",
        mini: "FSM",
        component: FullScreenMap
      },
      {
        path: "/maps/vector-maps",
        name: "Vector Map",
        mini: "VM",
        component: VectorMap
      }
    ]
  },
  { path: "/widgets", name: "Widgets", icon: WidgetsIcon, component: Widgets },
  { path: "/charts", name: "Charts", icon: Timeline, component: Charts },
  { path: "/calendar", name: "Calendar", icon: DateRange, component: Calendar },
  { redirect: true, path: "/", pathTo: "/dashboard", name: "Dashboard" }
];
export default dashRoutes;
```

How can I integrate the main routes file to incorporate the Creative Tim dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know when working with creative tim with react, just take(/copy) what you need from the "creative tim's dashboard example project" and paste it to your project.

Make sure you have the tools that creative tim works with, for example material-ui.

You may have some modification based on tools versions.